# How the create "Application file" for code in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a project in c++ with a sime gui (form)

I remember that the application file (file that runs the project) should be in the "Debug" directory of the project, but I don't find it. How can I create this file ?

Thanks

Comment: If you press F5, does it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the "Build / Build Solution" menu command?

Comment: And be sure that your build configuration is set to Debug, otherwise you may want to look for a "Release" directory instead.

Comment: Tried it..but the file is not in the Debug directory. It should be somewhere else?
EDIT: The configuration is "Debug"

Comment: OK, I found it. there is another "Debug" Directory. Thanks!